# Keep specific elements of large matrix product

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to compute the following matrix expression: `XT - Y` and keep elements *only corresponding to non-zero elements of matrix `Y`*. For example, if:

```
In [63]: X.dot(T.T) - Y
Out[63]: array([[ -6,  -2], [ -9, -12]])
In [64]: Y
Out[64]: array([[5, 0], [7, 8]])
```

Then the result should be `[[-6, 0], [-9, -12]]`.

`X` and `T` are both vectors. The problem is that both `X.dot(T.T)` and `Y` have a large size (say `350 x 23 000 000`), so `Y` is stored as a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` with about 200 million values. I haven't got enough memory to store intermediate `XT` result.

Sure, it is possible to iterate over all non-zero elements of `Y` and manually compute each element of `XT` and manually construct result `csc_matrix` then. Result will have the same `indices` and `indptr` attributes as `Y` and this makes me think that there should be a shorter or faster way.

Comment: In the context of numpy, the meaning of "vector" can be ambiguous.  You are using `X.dot(T.T)` to compute the outer product of `X` and `T`, so I assume `X` and `T` are stored as *2D* numpy arrays with shape `(350, 1)` and `(23000000, 1)` (and not as 1D arrays with shape `(350,)` and `(23000000,)`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

First, some sample data:

```
In [75]: X.T
Out[75]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [76]: T.T
Out[76]: array([[2, 3, 5, 7]])

In [77]: Y
Out[77]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [78]: Y.A
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 0, 4, 5],
       [6, 0, 0, 7],
       [0, 8, 0, 0]])
```

Convert `Y` to COO format (so the row and column indices of the nonzero data are readily available):

```
In [79]: C = Y.tocoo()
```

Compute the equivalent of `X.dot(T.T) - Y`, but only for values where `Y` is nonzero:

```
In [80]: data = X[C.row,0]*T[C.col,0] - C.data

In [81]: data
Out[81]: array([-2,  1,  1,  2,  7])
```

Compare to the full computation:

```
In [82]: X.dot(T.T) - Y
Out[82]: 
matrix([[ 2,  3,  1,  2],
        [-2,  6, 10,  7],
        [ 6,  1, 15, 21]])
```

If you need the result in a CSC matrix like `Y`:

```
In [84]: D = csc_matrix((data, (C.row, C.col)), shape=C.shape)

In [85]: D
Out[85]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [86]: D.A
Out[86]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2,  0,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0]])
```